# How to convert RGB color to grayscale in Java

Tags: java, colors

I'm trying to create a method that converts a given java.awt.Color color to grayscale. Here's what I have right now:

```
public Color gs(Color col) {
        if (grayScale) {
            float[] rgb = col.getRGBColorComponents(new float[3]);
            rgb[0] = rgb[1] = rgb[2] = (int)(0.299 * rgb[0] + 0.587 * rgb[1] + 0.114 * rgb[2]);
            col = new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
        }
        return col;
}
```

However, when I call this method, it seems to be returning the color black every single time, regardless of the input color. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float` components are in the range of `[0.0, 1.0]`. You are adding the scaled RGB components together and then casting them to `int`:

```
rgb[0] = rgb[1] = rgb[2] = (int)(0.299 * rgb[0] + 0.587 * rgb[1] + 0.114 * rgb[2]);
                            ^^^ Cast to int
```

You would get the color black if all of the values in the `rgb` array are zero. This is most likely because the cast to int truncates the resulting floating-point values down to zero. Since `rgb` is an array of floats, you should cast result to `float`.

```
rgb[0] = rgb[1] = rgb[2] =  (float)(0.299 * rgb[0] + 0.587 * rgb[1] + 0.114 * rgb[2]);
                           ^ Key change, cast to float
```

Comment: @user16320675 Sorry, I had a typo, thanks for catching. The result should cast to float, or, alternatively, one should use `f` suffixes on multipliers

Comment: Just tried this during English class and it works perfect, thank you!